# Empty Array after subscribe call

Tags: angular

I wrote a service:

```js
loadroom() : Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.roomUrl)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => {
                let resources = response;
                return resources.map(function(room:any) {
                    return {id: room.id, title: room.title, eventcolor: room.eventColor};
                });
            })
        );
}
```

Then I use this service in a component

```js
rooms: any[] = [];       
ngOnInit() {
    this.schedulerService.loadroom().subscribe(response => this.rooms = response);
    console.log(this.rooms);
}
```

I didn't see data in the array. In console I get an empty array  `[]`

But if I use

```js
this.schedulerService.loadroom().subscribe(response => {console.log(response)});
```

I get the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is completely the expected behavior, `subscribe`is asynchronous, meaning that calling it won't block the execution of the code, it won't wait for it to finish before executing the next line. So

```js
this.schedulerService.loadroom().subscribe(response => this.rooms=response);
    console.log(this.rooms);
```

Triggers the log before the subscription finished

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe is asynchronous. It's likely the execution isn't finished : you need to work in the chained event to keep the flow at this point. Anything you need to do with `this.rooms` need to be in the subscribe event.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Observable are asynchronous. Meaning `console.log(this.rooms);` happen **before** `response => this.rooms=response`.

So the correct way of using it is:

```js
this.schedulerService.loadroom().subscribe(response => {
  this.rooms = response;
  console.log(this.rooms);
});
```

Comment: I want to use "rooms" in the rest of the code. How do I get to update it globally?