# Angular14: variable assigned inside subscribe is empty outside subscribe.. why? And what have i missed?

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, subscribe, observers

I have a variable that i have instantiated in the top of my typescript class like this:

```
UserTimeRegistration: TimeRegistration[];
```

I have a method calling an api like this:

```
getUserInfo(UserID: string): Observable<TimeRegistration[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<TimeRegistration[]>(this.apiURL + '/TimeRegistrations/' + UserID)
      .pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

and I subscribe to it like this:

```
this.getUserInfo(this.smartTimeUser.UserID).subscribe((data: TimeRegistration[]) => {this.UserTimeRegistration = data;})
```

If I look at my variable inside the subscribe, i can see the value is assigned, but as soon as i move outside, its empty. I am probably missing something basic, but I have played with it for an hour without getting the point.. So I hope there is an expert here that shakes his head, rips out his hair and laugh at my stupidity before getting to his/her keyboard and type what I am doing wrong, how i should do it and why ;-)

I have tried multible variations, but i cant seem to figure out why it cant keep a variable after i leave subscribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**subscribe** is **asynchronous**

Please refer to this question for more understanding it already has a clear explantion...

[exisiting subscribe question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165159/empty-array-after-subscribe-call)

I think this might explain your doubt..  if not I need more details like where in the function the data from response is not accessible.. (code wise)

Comment: Perfect.. It made sense :-D